# Oracle INSTR backward in Oracle SQL Developer does not work.

Tags: regex, oracle, substring, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use regexp_substr and instr in Oracle SQL Developer to take a value from my database and go from right to left to the first "/" and then use the value to the right.

```
table name: access_log
col name: download
value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

I am trying to end up with just the **03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf** part of the value. I have the following SQL:

```
select regexp_substr(download, '(.*)/', instr(download,'/',1,4)+1,1,'i',1) 
from access_log;
```

But I am getting the following error in SQL Developer:

```
ORA-00939: too many arguments for function
00939. 00000 -  "too many arguments for function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error and how I can make this work

Comment: What is a type of `download` column?

Comment: Is there anything in your actual use case to force the combination of `REGEXP_INTSTR` and `INSTR`?

Comment: Easier approach: `regexp_replace(download, '.*/', '')`

Comment: Wumpus Q. Wumbley please post you answer and I give you credit

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the goal posts moved:
`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf', '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1') FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 2):

That `instr` and `regexp_substr` combination looks pretty complicated. You want everything after the last slash? The key to finding the simpler answer is a technique that often helps with regular expressions: If the problem seems hard, invert it. Instead of thinking about what you want to keep, think about what you want to get rid of.

In this case you want to get rid of everything up to and including the last slash, and that's a really easy regular expression: `.*/`

So just match that and replace it with the empty string.

```
regexp_replace(download, '.*/', '')
```

Comment: wait... this is not right... I need to go from the 2nd "/" from the  right to the first "1" from the right... I have to end up with "case"

Comment: Whilst your original query did return just "case" (and did not fail) for me (when I copied the example string, and run against DUAL), you did explicitely ask for "03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf" - which Wumpus Q. Wumbley provides…